# Bad URL when creating NSURL

Tags: iphone, nsurl

I am making request on server , having spaces in URL

http://xxxxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=showAllwedsdwewsdsd&params[]=Saudi%20Arab&params[]=all

I was getting the error Bad URL so ,

I used

```
   downloadURL = [downloadURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but due this I am getting strange URL as

```
 http://sdsdsdsdsdsd.com/api/api.php?func=showAllsdsd&params5262721536=Saudi              0X0P+0rabia&params5 8288=All
```

I am also using

```
  downloadURL= [downloadURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

but again strange url like

```
     http://xxxxxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=showsdsdsd&params[]=Saudi 0X1.240DC0D824P-807rabia&params[]=All
```

Please help how can I solve this issue

**Edit** Pasting Big portion of code

```
   PropertyXMLDownloader *download=[[PropertyXMLDownloader alloc]init];
  [download setDelegate:self];
   firstAppDelegate *del=(firstAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   NSLog(@"Country is %@",del.country);
   NSLog(@"State is %@",del.state);
//  del.country=[del.country stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

   NSString *downloadURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=showAll&params[]=Saudi Arabia&params[]=%@",@"all"];
      // downloadURL= [downloadURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
       //downloadURL = [downloadURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
   downloadURL = [[downloadURL componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant]    componentsJoinedByString:@"%20"];


    NSLog(downloadURL); 
    [download startDownloading:downloadURL];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
downloadURL = [[downloadURL componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant]   componentsJoinedByString:@"%20"];
```

Comment: api.php?func=showAllProperties&params[]=Saudi 0X1.4E0E40DB4EP-804rabia&params[]=all

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the %20 is being seen as a data argument, like %@ or %g. Try defining the NSString using

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=showAllwedsdwewsdsd&params[]=Saudi%20Arab&params[]=all"];
```

and you'll see a warning. 'Escaping' the percent sign by adding another in front of it:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=showAllwedsdwewsdsd&params[]=Saudi**%**%20Arab&params[]=all"];
```

and the warning goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
NSLog(downloadURL);
```

Try replacing it by:

```
NSLog(@"%@", downloadURL);
```

and everything will work.

You can use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` and forget about all the workarounds.

(Explanation: since `downloadURL` contains % signs, it will not play well with NSLog, which expect a format string as its first argument, where % signs identify placeholders to be replaced).

Comment: yes i am 100% sure , i used bebug , the url is not strange before it , also i used above  technique, but it is not working